# Update linked SQL server with parameters

Tags: sql, linked-server

I have two linked SQL servers and i am trying to issue an update on the other server but am getting an error "Statement(s) could not be prepared.", followed by "Must declare the scalar variable "@Shipper_Nbr""

The syntax i am using is:

```
update DBSERVER.DBNAME.DBO.TABLE set Field = @Value WHERE ID = @id
```

What is the correct way to do this?

UPDATE:

I tried using a stored procedure and get the same result. Also, i noticed additional information. The syntax checks out, i only get the error when i attempt to save the stored procedure. Also, i noticed the error also states "OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "WARSQLVS01" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed."."

ACK - i figured it out. It was a separate line where i was trying to pass the parameter from within OPENQUERY select statement. Sorry about that! :-\

Comment: That's an odd error to get, considering @Shipper_Nbr doesn't show up in the code you presented. Is there more you can share with us?

Comment: I was trying to keep it generic. Here is the actual statement:

  UPDATE WARSQLVS01.ISS3_AND_DHAM_PROD.dbo.ISS_AND_data_Shipments
  SET  Arrive_DT = @Actual_DateTime
  WHERE Shipper_Nbr = @Shipper_Nbr and
    Container_Name = @Container_Name

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what this problem is, but we have had to work round similar kinds of issues by setting up a stored proc on the remote server and calling that, rather than trying to manipulate the items on the remote server locally.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem is with the server link, and not something about the rest of your SQL statement? Where is the @Shipper_Nbr value assigned?

Comment: Yeah - @Shipper_Nbr is just a parameter to the stored procedure. It's used in other places in the stored procedure, but only indicates an error on this statement.

Comment: No, but i'll post the header to prove that the variable is declared:

alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[CSN_UpdatePoints_InTransit] (
 @Shipper_Nbr  varchar(6),
 @Container_Name  varchar(5),
 @Point    decimal(3,0),
 @Actual_DateTime datetime,
 @CustomerID   varchar(30) = 'SHAP'
)

Answer (score 0):

Se if this works

```
UPDATE T
SET Arrive_DT = @Actual_DateTime 
WHERE Shipper_Nbr = @Shipper_Nbr and Container_Name = @Container_Name 
FROM WARSQLVS01.ISS3_AND_DHAM_PROD.dbo.ISS_AND_data_Shipments  as T
```